# Radius of converge of $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^{2}\sqrt{n} + 1}x^{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am supposed to find where the power series:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^{2}\sqrt{n} + 1}x^{n}$$ converge absolutely, converge conditionally and where it diverges. My book only shows how to find the radius of convergence by using the ratio test. So I tried it:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{(n + 1)(n^{2}\sqrt{n} + 1)}{n((n + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} + 1)}\right|$$

But I am stuck here, even expanding this more out, I don't know how to find this limit (although I know it is $1$, right?).

Another hint that I got for solving this problem was to use the result I found in the previous task, where I found that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^{2}\sqrt{n} + 1}$ diverges by using the comparison test: $\frac{n}{n^{2}\sqrt{n} + 1} < \frac{1}{n^{3 / 2}}$.

So, how can I find this radius of convergence? How can I use the result that I found?

Comment: How you know the limit is equal to $1$? It is true. You can show that by pulling the highest power of $n$ from the numerator and denominator, just a standard calculus question on limits. What can you conclude about the radius of convergence if you see that the limit is $1$?

Comment: @Shashi Yes true, I could see it but I don't know how to expand this to find the highest term and thought maybe it would not be sufficient to just say that I "could see it". But I guess it is. Either way, am I correct if I say this converges conditionally for $x \leq -1$?

Comment: You mean if $x=-1$? It converges absolutely for $x=-1$. Use comparison test for that.

Comment: I did use the comparison test, comparing with $\frac{1}{n^{3 / 2}}$. So I thought it cannot converge absolutely because of this. However it looks to me as it converges conditionally for $x \leq 1$ by the alternating series test

Comment: How? Comparing with $1/n^{3/2}$ is fine. You know that the series of $1/n^{3/2}$ converges, right?

Comment: Ah I think I confused $\frac{3}{2}$ with $\frac{2}{3}$!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n + 1)(n^{2}\sqrt{n} + 1)}{n((n + 1)^{\frac{5}{2}} + 1)}$$is equal to $1$, because it is basically the limit of $\frac{n^{7/2}}{n^{7/2}}$. Therefore, the radius of convergence is $1$.